# How to make an object change its look on collision with another object in corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk, collision-detection

I'm making a game where there's an egg and you have to keep it from falling on the ground and breaking, I can't find the code to make it look broken if it hits the ground. I'm using corona sdk so if you know the answer please help!

Comment: Welcome. Please provide the code you have tried so far.

Comment: you will use spritesheet images to have an animation for broken egg

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to change the image.  Sprites are probably the most logical, but you could simply destroy the whole egg and draw the broken egg at the place of the whole egg with a new call to display.newImageRect().